# Importing data from MS Access DB into MySQL DB with ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ms-access, activerecord, database-migration

I am building a Rails 5 app which will be a replacement for a Microsoft Access based solution and I need to import the data from Access into the Rails app's MySQL database.

It's worth noting that I would like for relations and default values to be preserved and reflected in the destination database.

I have seen a few approaches to this, but they were all quite old solutions. I was hoping to get the 2017 answer to this.

One way I think this could be done, is to export the data from MS Access into a temporary MySQL database, validate all the relations and verify the data is all there. Then use ActiveRecord to import the data from the temporary MySQL database into the Rails app's MySQL database. I think this would stage the data migration and mean that there is less to go wrong.

Is this on the right track? Or are there better ways this can be done?

If you need any more information, let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use mdb gem (link: [mdb gem for more detail](https://github.com/cph/mdb)

1. install mdb gem

   ```
   group :development, :test do
     gem 'mdb'
   end
   ```
2. how to use it

   ```
   database = Mdb.open("app/assets/mdb/your_access_file.mdb")
   database.tables  
       # will list tables, for example you have table customer inside access
   @customers = database["customer"] 
       # this will put tables customer to activerecord model @customers
   @customers.last
   @customers.count
   ```
3. then you can use activerecord commands  to transfer it to your mysql tables with loop or sql commands

Hope this helps.